# Convert columns to rows in datagridview

Tags: c#

Is it possible to convert columns to rows in datagridview?

I have the initial data set below in my datagridview:

```
Branch     Costcenter   Total

cebu       6000          10

           7000          20

           8000          30
```

and I want the final output in my datagridview to be as seen below:

```
BRANCH 

cebu       6000 7000 8000  10 20 30
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Better to do it in My SQL. Use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

select CONCAT(center,' ', val1 ,' ' ,val2 )from ( 
SELECT center ,GROUP_CONCAT(val1 SEPARATOR ' ') val1,GROUP_CONCAT(val2 SEPARATOR ' ') val2
FROM Costcenter GROUP BY center) x